# How to add custom logic in odoo10 e-commerce module? Which model in odoo10 should I inherit to extend e-commerce cart logic?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11, odoo-view

I want to add some custom logic into odoo 10 e-commerce module. I know I have to create a new addon for that. But I am not getting from where I should start the module development.

As the developer mode not helping me in website module to show elements properties when I hover over it. So I am not getting the model's name, field name.. What are the starting steps towards this development?

I want to change the logic in web when we add product to the cart I want to serve that product on monthly basis so select 2 dates, and then the regular billing for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the source code of the modules related to website_sale, you could find it online at:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/11.0/addons